How to Delete any layout from vertical layout of GUI created using PyQt in python
I want to have an dynamic GUI in which I can add or delete any layout. So for adding layout in GUI I am using temporary variables and add them in layout. now when I want to delete any layout from mid and add layout at the mid. How can I do it.
image:

In this Image, Every line is one Horizontal layout in vertical layout. I want to delete layout from it using cross sign and add layout using plus sign button. I want to add any number of layout and delete any number of layout. How can I do it.
    row = QHBoxLayout()
    checkbox = QCheckBox()
    line = QLineEdit()
    line.setFixedSize(220,30)
    browse = QPushButton()
    browse.clicked.connect(self.browse_file)
    browse.setFixedSize(30,30)
    browse.setIcon(QIcon(os.path.join(os.getcwd(),"open-folder-with-document.png")))
    text_editor = QPushButton()
    text_editor.setFixedSize(30,30)
    text_editor.setIcon(QIcon(os.path.join(os.getcwd(),"text_edit.png")))
    modify_block = QPushButton()
    modify_block.setFixedSize(30,30)
    modify_block.setIcon(QIcon(os.path.join(os.getcwd(),"Modify_block.png")))
    delete_button = QPushButton()
    delete_button.setFixedSize(30,30)
    delete_button .setIcon(QIcon(os.path.join(os.getcwd(),"delete.png")))
    plus_button = QPushButton()
    plus_button.setFixedSize(30,30)
    plus_button.setIcon(QIcon(os.path.join(os.getcwd(),"Plus.png")))
    row.addWidget(checkbox)
    row.addWidget(line)
    row.addWidget(browse)
    row.addWidget(text_editor)
    row.addWidget(modify_block)
    row.addWidget(delete_button)
    row.addWidget(plus_button)
    self.elements.addLayout(row)
'''
I am using this code to add layout. I tried to create layout and element as a part of class using self and global variable but I don't know maximum number of horizontal layout. it can me 300-350 layout.


You need to get a dynamic reference that allows you to identify the row of the pressed button within the vertical layout.
One possibility could be to make a list of all delete buttons and connect their signals with a lambda (or partial) or by using sender():
    self.deleteButtons = []

def addRow(self):
    # your code as above
    ...
    self.deleteButtons.append(delete_button)
    delete_button.clicked.connect(self.deleteRowFromButton)

def deleteRowFromButton(self):
    button = self.sender()
    index = self.deleteButtons.index(button)
    hbox = self.elements.itemAt(index).layout()
    while hbox.count():
        item = hbox.itemAt(0)
        if item.widget():
            widget = item.widget()
            hbox.removeWidget(widget)
            widget.deleteLater()
    self.deleteButtons.remove(button)

Note that the above works only as long as self.elements only has widgets/layouts added as you show above: if other elements are added, the index retrieved above will obviously not be consistent.
Consider that in these situations a better approach is to "group" the widgets of each row within a QWidget subclass, which allows better modularity and provides more consistent management through custom signals:
class ElementRow(QWidget):
    deleteRequest = pyqtSignal(object)
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        layout = QHBoxLayout(self)
        self.checkBox = QCheckBox()

        ... create all items and add them to the layout

        self.delete_button.clicked.connect(lambda:
            self.deleteRequest.emit(self))

Then, in the main class, you do something like the following:
def addRow(self):
    row = ElementRow()
    self.elements.addWidget(row)
    row.deleteRequest.connect(self.deleteRow)

def deleteRow(self, element):
    self.elements.removeWidget(element)
    element.deleteLater()


@Kskrishna You're welcome. If this answer solved your problem, consider to mark it as accepted by clicking the gray tick on its left.

@musicmante. what is element in delete Row function. If I want to add layout in the middle how that can be possible do you have any idea?. Like here we are deleting from middle in a same way i want to add layout.

@Kskrishna element is the ElementRow instance (emitted as self in the signal of the lambda). If you properly use that solution, adding any other layout or widget within the same layout wouldn't matter. Just use insertWidget or insertLayout as explained in the documentation of QBoxLayout.
